# My keyboard tab and spacebar button both are not working properly in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard, whitespace, code-editor, vscode-keybinding

I've faced this problem recently, when I press tab or spacebar button in vscode it doesn't add whitespace rather than it just blinking and not working properly.

My keyboard is alright I've checked all keys and I uninstall vs code in several times but it still doesn't fix. How can I solve it?

Comment: Welcome! 1) Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. 2) What do you see when you [troubleshoot your keybindings](//github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues)? Please paste the relevant parts of what you see into a code block in your question post. 3) What extension have you installed? Did you install the VS Code Vim extension?